AWS CloudSearch Domain missing results
I am working on getting some data from AWS CloudSearch Domain and am having issues with the result set having duplicated results, and missing data results. Here is my code:
    private List<Hit> queryAws(String query, String fields) {
        AmazonCloudSearchDomain client = initializeClient();

        List<Hit> hits = new ArrayList<>();
        String nextCursor = "initial";
        boolean hasMore = true;

        do {
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest().withQuery(query);
            searchRequest.setQueryOptions("{\"fields\": [\""+ fields + "\"]}");
            searchRequest.setCursor(nextCursor);

            SearchResult result = client.search(searchRequest);
            hits.addAll(result.getHits().getHit());

            nextCursor = result.getHits().getCursor();

            if (result.getHits().getHit().isEmpty()) {
                hasMore = false;
            }
        }while(hasMore);

        return hits;
    }

We are using the old V1 SDK. However we are unable to update to the non-osgi V2.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.534</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

I need to use the Cursor in lieu of the normal pagination because i need more than 10,000 results (max allowed for pagination).
There seems to be very little information/docs related to using the cursor, so it is possible i missed something.
